# How to DRY my given code in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have this code in my controller and it's a bit long. Can anyone guide me how to DRY this:

```
def edit
    @employee = Employee.where(id: params[:id]).first
    unless @employee.profile
      @employee.build_profile
    end
    unless @employee.current_address
      @employee.build_current_address
    end
    unless @employee.permanent_address
      @employee.build_permanent_address
    end
    unless @employee.emergency_contact
      @employee.build_emergency_contact
    end
    unless @employee.attachments
      @employee.attachments.build
    end
  end
```

Comment: defensive programming often smells bad. You should have complete valid entries in db, create a rake task and update all if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take help of model in this case,

in controller,

```
def edit
  @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
  @employee.create_association_instance  
end
```

and in employee.rb model create new method,

```
def create_association_instance
  self.build_profile unless self.profile    
  self.build_current_address unless self.current_address
  self.build_permanent_address unless self.permanent_address    
  self.build_emergency_contact unless self.emergency_contact    
 self.attachments.build unless self.attachments 
end
```